# Hiding Popup Div is not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a popup div i want to make it visible when a asp button is clicked but the problem is it doesn't hide when i click the close span of popup div, although it is working fine inside the page load event it hides there, but it is not hiding when it becomes visible by the asp button.

Javascipt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("#popup_homeBanner .close").click(function () {
             $("#popup_homeBanner").hide();
         });
     });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div runat="server" id="divBanner" visible="False">
    <div id="popup_homeBanner">    
        <span class="close icon-cancel">close</span>
        <div style="margin: 5% 10% 5% 20%; padding: 10px; border: 0px solid; 
             border-radius: 20px; width: 60%; height: 80%; background-color: 
             #FFFFFF; background-image: url('Banner/Announcement.jpg');  
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-position: center center; background-size: cover;"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

C#:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    divBanner.Visible = true;   
 }
```

CSS:

```
#popup_homeBanner{float:Left; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; position:fixed; z-index:100; background: url(../images/opacity_bg.png) left top repeat; text-align:center; display:block;}
#popup_homeBanner .close{position:absolute; display:inline-block; background:#fff; width:50px; padding-right:6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;    
-border-radius: 15px;    
-moz-border-radius:15px;
-khtml-border-radius:15px; margin-top:16px; left:50%; cursor:pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing you are able to bind the close function the way you are doing it. Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
$('#divBanner').on('click', '.close', function(){
 $('#divBanner').hide();
});
     });
</script>
```